# Recording video from a USB camera

Tags: android, video, usb, android-camera, android-video-player

Calling all Android video-over-usb experts! I've spent weeks trying to get to grips with what I need to do to display and record a video stream from an external USB-connected video camera.  It's easy enough using the device's built-in camera, but doing it via USB seems to be a big problem.

I've seen a number of YouTube videos of people who have managed to connect a USB Video Class (UVC) camera to display a video stream, but as far as I can make out, this seems to require a rooted device and a custom ROM, which I want to avoid.

I read somewhere that there is a fundamental problem with USB on Android (something about ISOChronous transfer?) that makes it very difficult (impossible?) to read and record video over USB.  But I also read somewhere else that later Android versions (4.1+) have addressed this problem, although I'm unable to confirm that.

Does anyone in the SO community know whether I can do this without rooting, or creating a custom ROM?  Or am I asking too much of Android here?

If it's possible to do this without going native (JNI/NDK), that would be perfect.  If there's a forum or a tutorial that covers this that somebody knows about, that would be great, but any info would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, Are you having the solution for this? Because I also tried but I couldn't find a way? If you know please share with me. Thanks!

Comment: There are a bunch of Android apps if you search "USB Camera" (https://play.google.com/store/search?q=usb%20camera&c=apps); although, there's no native way I've found. If your software supports USB cameras, you should be in good shape.